# Multiple key presses detected on SFML, can't solve it in any other way and works differently on different machines

Tags: c++, networking, sfml

this is my first post here.
I am trying to solve a problem I am having with my SFML project where I am using multiple clients, that communicate through texts that can be typed in the rendered window and then sent to the other sockets using a selector.
My problem is that everytime i press one button of the keyboard, the window detects like 3 or 4, and if I try it on another machine, the behaviour changes.
I tried almost every solution, including the setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

This is the update function

```
void Client::Update(Input* input,sf::Event& Ev, sf::Font& font, sf::RenderWindow& window)
{

        if (input->isKeyDown(sf::Keyboard::Return))
        {
            sf::Packet packet;
            packet << id + ": " + text;
            socket.send(packet);
            sf::Text displayText(text, font, 20);
            displayText.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            chat.push_back(displayText);
            text = "";
            input->setKeyUp(sf::Keyboard::Return);
        }
        else if (input->isKeyDown(sf::Keyboard::Backspace))
        {
            if (text.size() > 0)
                text.pop_back();
        }
        else if (input->isKeyDown(sf::Keyboard::Space))
        {
            text += ' ';
        }
        else if (Ev.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
        {
                text += Ev.text.unicode;
                return;
        }
        //sf::Event::TextEntered
        //text += Ev.text.unicode;

}
```

This is the render one.

```
void Client::Render(sf::Font& font, sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    sf::Packet packet;
    socket.receive(packet);
    std::string temptext;
    if (packet >> temptext)
    {
        sf::Text displayText(temptext, font, 20);
        displayText.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        chat.push_back(displayText);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < chat.size(); i++)
    {
        chat[i].setPosition(0, i * 20);
        window.draw(chat[i]);
    }
    sf::Text drawText(text, font, 20);
    drawText.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    drawText.setPosition(0, i * 20);

    window.draw(drawText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the `isKeyDown` function as part of SFML, so I assume you either is something you implemented or is part of a previous version of SFML (being the current 2.5.1).

There are three ways to detect input from keyboard in SFML.

1. [`sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#a80a04b2f53005886957f49eee3531599): looks like this is the one you are using. It will be true every cycle that the key is pressed. You definetly don't want this. The `window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false)` will obviously not work because you don't get the input through the window, but directly from the keyboard.
2. [`sf::Event::KeyPressed` and `sf::Event::KeyReleased`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php#the-keypressed-and-keyreleased-events) events: for this, `window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false)` will work, but still it's not the recommended way to deal with text input, as it would require a lot of juggling by your side to handle key combinations (accents, uppa.
3. [`sf::Event::TextEntered`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php#the-textentered-event) event: now, this is the best and recommended way to handle typing. Check the tutorial to see how to use it.